# How to operate the Perl debugger in Eclipse/EPIC

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

I have installed ActivePerl, and I would like to debug a Perl program using Eclipse and EPIC.

I have installed Eclipse and EPIC, they look OK. (It's doing basic syntax checking on an example Perl program).
I then used PPM to install PadWalker (since that's what they say is needed to use the step debugger).

Now, in Eclipse, when I try to step through the program, I get the error: "Error: install PadWalker module to see local variables".

In PPM, I notice that it had installed PadWalker in area: "site", while all other Perl modules are installed in area: "perl".

For area: "site", @INC shows: ... .../Environments/Active Perl/site/lib

and for area: "perl", @INC shows: ... .../Environments/Active Perl/lib

What should I do?

My system: Windows 7 x64.

Comment: perl (modules that come with Perl) vs site (modules that didn't come with Perl) is a red herring. Both are searched for modules. Sorry I can't help you more than that. My only guess is that you have more than one install of Perl, and Padwalker is not installed in the one EPIC is using.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another forum. One has to install the "testing" EPIC version. Then the debugger works. (only after a certain bug in Cwd.pm is fixed). (On Windows).